# Arguments field for functions without input parameters in roxygen2

Tags: r, r-package, cran, roxygen2

In an R package, how can I activate the arguments field (\arguments{}) for a function that does not have any input parameters?
I might be able to add it manually in the .Rd file and submit it to CRAN; however, I wonder if there is any automated way to do this.

Comment: If there are no inputs why are you looking to document arguments?

Comment: I received a comment from reviewers to include the arguments field, even for functions that do not have arguments. May be:
Arguments
None

Comment: I would push back on that.  There are lots of examples of base R functions with no arguments, e.g. `R.Version()`.  These don't have any `\arguments` sections in their Rd files.

Comment: I agree with @user2554330 - their word isn't law and if your functions don't have arguments then it doesn't seem like you should need an arguments field.  If they have a different opinion they can provide explicit guidance.  Now if you have a github or something where we could look over the code/documentation we might be able to provide more guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I manually added them, and the package has been accepted.